# Connect my WD USB HD to a Buffalo NAS

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, buffalo-nas

I can format my Western Digital USB HD either NTFS or exFAT. I tried both. This happens:

exFAT: I can see the USB device in the admin tool of the NAS but it doesn't give any information (such as memory capacity). I cannot see it in Windows either.
NTFS: I can see the USB device and can access it via Windows Network. But I can only read but not write on the device. I cannot change its security settings or ownership.
My guess is that when Windows formats the device, it doesn't allow Linux users to write on the device. I tried to give full access to "Anyone" when hooked to the PC. But it still won't work when connected to the NAS. Maybe it would work if I gave as the computername the name of the NAS?

Or do you know other things I might try? It's a WD USB device and I read that formatting to Ext3 is not so easy to do.

My settings: OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit NAS: Buffalo Terastation

Comment: Why not format it using FAT32?  The NTFS issue is likely due to the NTFS driver that the NAS is using - some linux NTFS drivers do not support writes.  Probably similar issues for exFAT.

Comment: I need to store large files on this USB disk. FAT32 only allows 4GB  per file.

Comment: If you don't need it elsewhere, why not format it XFS?  Isn't that the default format for the TeraStation?  I'm also not sure why ext3 wouldn't work . . .

Comment: okay, I've finally fixed my issue. I downloaded gparted live and burnt it on a cd. boot from cd and connected the WD HD. Formatted to EXT3 which took about half an hour. Now the device is recognized on the NAS and i can write on it. thanks for helping me out!

Comment: As a note, I believe you could have formatted the drive from the TerraStation management software . . .